# - connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: never call

Tags: objective-c, http, progress

I want to notify my user about the progress of the upload of some Mpeg 3 files. Just one.
but I get issue as I say in the title.

My upload code is here

```c
- (NSString *) upload: (NSData*) postData {

    NSString *str;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/test.php"];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";


    NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";
    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add mp3 data
    if (postData) {

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=audio\r\n", @"audioFormKey"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/mpeg3\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:postData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength2 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSLog(postLength2);



    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if(data.length > 0)
        {
            NSError *error;
            NSURLResponse *response;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(str);
        }
    }];
    return str;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

    NSLog(@"bytes transfer %li" ,(long)bytesWritten);

}
```

Here the Log "bytes transfer" is never call.

Thanks a lot for support

Answer (score 0):

A bit odd to be calling `sendAsynchronousRequest:` and then `sendSynchronousRequest:` in the completion handler?

In any case, you aren't configuring the URL connection to have a delegate and, thus, your delegate method is never called.

You'll need to allocated and instantiate the URLConnection and then configure it to use your object as the delegate.  And it needs to conform to the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol.

Comment: It works I update Method with NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                    initWithRequest:request
                                    delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];

Comment: @user3279327 Excellent!  Now, you still have that synchronous request embedded in an async request.  That seems like it'll download the request twice, which probably isn't what you want?